# Required "token" not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN"

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using `PHP 7.4.1` and `Laravel Framework 6.20.16`.

I am trying to implement the following library: [telegram-bot-sdk](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/initial-setup) and the following version `"irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "^2.0",`

After installing the sdk and getting my private token from telegram's `@botfather`. I am trying to use the sdk.

I created a route and a controller:

*route*

```
Route::get('telegramHello', 'TelegramController@getHello');
```

*controller*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Telegram\Bot\Api as Telegram;
use App\Helpers\TelegramResponse as Response;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function getHello() {
        $api = new Telegram(); // ----> HERE I GET THE ERROR

        $response = $api->getMe();
        return Response::handleResponse($response);
    }
//...
```

When opening my route I get the following exception:

[image]

The thing I do not understand is that I have created the config `telegram.php` and loading my correct token from my `.env` file:

[image]

In my `.env` file it looks like the following:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Try with putting `TELEGRAM_BOT_PRIVATE_TOKEN="value:here"` in [double quotes](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#usage).

Comment: I checked this [line](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/develop/src/Api.php#L56), here if you don't supply the token within the constructor it looks for env name is named as `TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN` so you can try to change the name of env variable to `TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN` in your .env

Comment: Thx works now. I followed the two tips above and it worked!

Comment: If you could specify exactly what you did in the answer it will close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two comments above helped me the most:

1. Use `""` for your `TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN`
2. Instead of using your own named `.env` variable use `TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN`

I hope this works also for others that have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Facade, not original API class. Your config is correct, you just using wrong class.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;
use App\Helpers\TelegramResponse as Response;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function getHello() {

        $response = Telegram::getMe();
        return Response::handleResponse($response);
    }
//...
```

---

Also i may recommend you using [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot) instead of `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk`. I created it as irazasyed's was poorly documented and really buggy at a lot of places.